# How to get first instance of function name including the parentheses?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get the function name from a string.

For example:
`str = "this is a function name this.function() and there are more text"` and I want to extract first instance of `this.function()` from it. The str is not consistent and the function name can be anything and can be repeated but it always has a dot in the middle and trailing opening and closing parentheses with or without parameters.

How can I do this using Python re?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
str = "this is a function name this.function() and there are more text"
x = re.search("\w*\.\w*\(.*\)",str)
```

The script matches a word, a period followed by a word and parantheses.

Incase you need to find all the instances, use `re.findall()`.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't match if there are words inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Ok, forgot about that. Fixed it in the edit now.